# SQLite query compare content Values

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listview, android-sqlite

How can I compare column content values? So if content values contain "ted" return all data in cursor.

```
public Cursor listNotes() {

    String username = session.getUser();
    String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE " +help.Column_owner+ " = " +username  ;
    Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, null);
    return c;
 }
```

Here is the error, I am trying to compare username to the content values in the column_create but its not working

```
 no such column: ted (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Notes WHERE column_owner = ted
```

Comment: Can you post your Task table definition?? @NoobCoder

Answer (score 0):

`username` must be enclosed in apostrophes (**'**), because it is a **string**!

Correct your code like this:

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE " + help.Column_owner + " = '" +username + "'";
```

Or, **better**, use a bound parameter (in this case, Android takes care of the apostrophes for you and you're less prone to SQL injection - and, last but not least, you use less string concatenations):

```
String query = "SELECT * FROM Task WHERE " + help.Column_owner + " = ?";
Cursor c = db.rawQuery(query, new String[]{username});
```